# How to drop a a empty row with the row name called None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, command-line

I want to create a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
>>> open csv_file.csv
```

and then, because I am using a MacBook, it opens Numbers. And I want it to look like this:

```
    ___________________________________________________________________________________
    |How was your day?|Did you spend money?| How much money did you spend?| Description|
   0|     good        |          yes       |                $40           |we ate pizza!|
```

but instead, I get this:

```
    ___________________________________________________________________________________
    |How was your day?|Did you spend money?| How much money did you spend?| Description|
   0|     good        |          yes       |                $40           |we ate pizza!|
None|                 |                    |                              |             |
```

here is the code for it:

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw


cal = qtw.QCalendarWidget()
date = cal.selectedDate()
saving_columns_show = {"How was your day" : "good","Did you spend money":"no" , "How much money did you spend":"nope", "Description":"nothin special"}
item_price_show = {"item name":"nope", "item price":"nipe"}

name = .date.toString("yyyy")+"_"+.date.toString("M")+"_"+.date.toString("d")
df_columns_by_date = pd.DataFrame(saving_columns_show, index = [0])
print("shape",.df_columns_by_date.shape)
print("df",.df_columns_by_date)
df_item_price = pd.DataFrame(item_price_show, index = [0])
file_1 = open(str(name)+ ".csv",'w')
df_columns_by_date.drop(labels=[1], axis=0)
create_write=.df_columns_by_date.to_csv(file_1, sep=",")
print(type(create_write))
file_1.write(str(create_write))
file_1.close()
```

I think that's all that you need. even though it's not the whole program. Tell me if I didn't include something that was used in the code.

anyway, I tried looking at other stackoverflow questions but couldn't find any. I tried using `replace` and many others just couldn't find any. How can I fix this?

Comment: whats your code?

Comment: `csv = csv.drop(labels=[1], axis=0)`

Comment: sean does the code work on mac?

Comment: well, not exaclty

Comment: then what does it do

Comment: it gives me this error:

Comment: KeyError: '[1] not found in axis'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found out how to drop it! it turns out that the line:`create_write=.df_columns_by_date.to_csv(file_1, sep=",")` actually already creates a `.csv` file. So, All I had to do was to delete these lines:

```
file_1 = open(str(name)+ ".csv",'w')
file_1.write(str(create_write))
file_1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(replace with whatever your dataframe is called) also why are you not opening with pandas? df = pd.read_csv()

```
df.drop(['None'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: KeyError: "['None'] not found in axis"

Comment: This line and the cmd line said

Comment: no this is to create a csv file, not to read one

Comment: is there a way to use to_csv()

Comment: If that is the case, whatever your code before you open it in numbers needs to be shown. Otherwise, nobody can help my person.

Comment: *the, lolz, just pls tell me if  you can help